# Horizontal border between 2 DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

[image]

And instead of 2 separate borders which causes alignment issues (As you can probably tell) I want to put a long border which spans the first left div and continues into the second bigger div so it's clear which description belongs to which group.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
<DIV ID="sideleftsmall">
      <h2>Name of Group</h2>
      <br />
      <span class='border'>Centennial College Dance Group</span>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <span class='border'>Basketball Group</span>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <span class='border'>Weight Loss Group</span>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <span class='border'>Asian Social Group</span>
      <br />
      <span class='border'>LGBTQ Group</span>
      <br />
      <span class='border'>Study Group - Math 185</span>
      <br />
      <span class='border'>Study Group - Web</span>
      <br />
      <span class='border'>Study Group - Linux</span>
    </DIV>
        <DIV ID="content">
          <h2 class='alted' style='margin-top: -4.9%; margin-bottom: 3%;'>Description</h2><br />
          <p class='border alted'>Centennial College Dance Group provides the opportunity for dancers, fanatics and coaches who enjoy all kinds of dance to participate in dance events every week catering to various levels of media involving dance. <br />Centennial College Dance Group programs and volunteer activities are funded and supported by the Scarborough Dance Recreation Parks and Wildlife Foundation, membership fees, user fees, corporate sponsors and fund raising activities.</p>
          <br /><br />
          <p class='border alted'>Thursdays at the gym open time we book a court – need at least 6 people for pick-up games.</p>
          <br /><br /><br />
          <p class='border alted'>Meet in gym – work out in groups of 3 or 4.  Arrange times/events on our site.</p>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
```

As you can see I'm currently using break lines to align, which is causes a lot of problems.

Doing tables causes this:

[image]

How would I align and size them properly?

Comment: You might post some markup so we can get a better idea of what we're working with here :)

Comment: why don't you just use a table? surely you can use css and/or js to keep the 'rows' having same height, but a simple table should be the simplest.

Comment: @ryenus How would I go about doing that between 2 divs? Sorry if I seem pretty nooby, I'm working on no sleep lol

Comment: Semantically a table would work, Since it looks like you're specifying clubs as well as their meeting times or more information about them. . I would recommend [reading up on HTML table markup](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) You should be able to take the content in those divs and throw them in some `<td>` tags, provided you study the examples for table markup :)

Comment: Just google: "html table mdn"

Comment: I don't think tables are the way to go unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good basic set up without css classes with some of your data that should help you start making your table. Hope it helps. if you include the table in one div it will look nice and neat.
The table border is not supported in html5.

```
<div id="sideleftsmall">
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Name of group</th>
  <th>Description</th>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Centennial College Dance Group</td>
  <td>Centennial College Dance Group provides the opportunity for dancers, fanatics and coaches who enjoy all kinds of dance to participate in dance events every week catering to various levels of media involving dance. <br />Centennial College Dance Group programs and volunteer activities are funded and supported by the Scarborough Dance Recreation Parks and Wildlife Foundation, membership fees, user fees, corporate sponsors and fund raising activities.</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Basketball Group</td>
  <td>Thursdays at the gym open time we book a court – need at least 6 people for pick-up games.</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Weight Loss Group</td>
  <td>Meet in gym – work out in groups of 3 or 4.  Arrange times/events on our site.</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your `<br>` and `<span>` tags are making this much more difficult than it should be. I would recommend replacing them with a `<ul>`

```
<DIV ID="sideleftsmall">
      <h2 class="title">Name of Group</h2>
      <ul>
      <li class='border'>Centennial College Dance Group</li>
      <li class='border'>Basketball Group</li>
      <li class='border'>Weight Loss Group</li>
      <li class='border'>Asian Social Group</li>
      <li class='border'>LGBTQ Group</li>
      <li class='border'>Study Group - Math 185</li>
      <li class='border'>Study Group - Web</li>
      <li class='border'>Study Group - Linux</li>
    </ul>
    </DIV>
```

As far as your alignment issues go, you'll need to make sure both containers (`#sideleftsmall` and `#content`) have the same top padding and top margin. You will also need to make sure and style both of your `<h2>` tags identically. This means you need to get away from the inline `style=""` and assign them the same class instead.

Here's some CSS to start out with

```
.title {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
#sideleftsmall ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px; /*align with header*/
}

#sideleftsmall ul li {
    padding: 3px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about Semantic Code in this case we should use `Definition List` **(check below why)**. First lets see the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/todupibo/1)**.

**A Small Description is here why we should use `Definition List` here?**

```
<dl>: Container
<dt>: Definition Term (like a title)
<dd>: Definition Description
```

**Here is the CSS Code to align the items.**

```
* {
 padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
dl {
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#f5f5f5;
  clear:left;
}

dt, dd
{float:left; 
  min-height:70px; /* will work till you know the max height of dd i.e. definition*/
border-bottom:1px solid #999;
width:50%;
  padding:15px 0;
}
dd{width:50%;}
```

**UPDATED VERSION**  check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nipukewi/1)**

The problem with the above approach it was not responsive i.e. when resize the browser the layout brakes. this could be solved by adding one extra markup and wrapping `dt` and `dd` inside the div.

**New CSS Code is**

```
dl > div {
  display: table-row;
  width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#f5f5f5;

}
dl > div > dt {
  display: table-cell;
   min-height:70px; 
  width:50%;
   padding:15px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;

}
dl > div > dd {
  display: table-cell;
  width:50%;
   padding:15px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
```

**HTML code is**

```
<dl>
   <div>
      <dt>Centennial College Dance Group</dt>
        <dd>And instead of 2 separate borders which causes alignment issues (As you can probably tell) I want to put a long border which spans the first left div and continues into the second bigger div so it's clear which description belongs to which group.
        </dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

> **NOTE: But This trick will work till you know the `max height` of the `dd` i.e. if you know how much amount of content
>   will be in `dd`.**

Comment: @Austen have a look at this answer. is that work for you

Comment: It looks out of alignment on my end =(

Comment: can you share a screenshot please

Comment: have a look at updated DEMO now. http://jsbin.com/nipukewi/1.. updated the answer as well.